# How Java's Regex use example would look in C#

Tags: c#, regex

In Java where I have to find all matching text to the specified regex I will write:

```
public class RegexDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" [a-z]{3} ");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("Alice has a cat "); //matcher which will analyze given text
        while(m.find()){//untile matcher finds matching text
            System.out.println(m.group()); //it prints the last found text substring
        }
    }
}
```

How the same thing would look in C#? I looked for some examples but in those examples they check if entire `string` matches the regex. I want to cut out the part that matches.

Comment: That would be [`Regex.Matches()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look a bit like this:

```
var re = new Regex(" [a-z]{3} ");
var matches = re.Matches("Alice has a cat ");
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Although in C#, it's common to skip that first step of creating a `Regex` instance and use the static methods instead, like this:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("Alice has a cat ", " [a-z]{3} ");
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would replicate your functionality:

```
public class RegexDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {        
        Regex p = new Regex(" [a-z]{3} ");
        var groups = p.Match("Alice has a cat ").Groups; //matcher which will analyze given text
        foreach(var group in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
public class RegexDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {        
        Regex p = new Regex(" [a-z]{3} ");
        var matches= p.Matches("Alice has a cat "); //matcher which will analyze given text
        foreach(var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match .Value);
        }
    }
}
```